How to grant access to a flow in a Managed Package
I'm developing a managed package and delivered a screen flow.  I installed the package in a testing org and want to grant access to the flow.  When I view the flow in the list and hit the dropdown arrow, the "Edit Access" option is not available.  I can allow a user to run the flow by assigning a permission set that grants the "Run Flows" permission.  But, some subscribers may not wish to give users permissions to run all flows and would rather grant fine-grained accesss.
Does anyone know why the "Edit Access" option is not available for the flow in the package and if there's any way to resolve granting access to users to the screen flow?

If you want subscribers to edit the flow, either make it a template (so multiple copies with new names can be made that are editable) or make it overridable (so one copy can be made that replaces the packaged version).

BTW worth noting the packaged template/overridable flow can also be active, making it directly usable as-is without copying first.

I thought about templates but I for now I don't really want to make the flow editable in the installed orgs.  I did add a support case but I don't hold out much hope.  I have had it takes week to get to someone who doesn't know the stock answers.
Maybe it can't work but it just doesn't say that anywhere and template would be the only option.  I'll keep digging.  Thanks for the reply.

can you set the "Edit Access" in your managed package org?

WHen you say "managed package org" do you mean the (1st gen) packaging org?
I can get to access there.  I'm wondering if I have to check "Override default behavior and restrict access to enabled profiles or permission sets." (even if I don't add any users)  in order to make the access editable in the installation org.

I think I figured it out.  I can enable the override checkbox in the flow definition before packaging.  Then I can add permission to run that flow in a perm set we ship.  That should allow running with users that have the perm set we ship.  I think I'm all set.
I won't be able to test until I build another package which I won't do for a while as I have to start from scratching setting up with a Beta package.  But with the next upload, I'll test it.
